# Loadbalancing with Nginx error not redirecting properly

Tags: ssl, nginx

I was able to get the load balancer to work only on inception. It seems that when I do any clicks on the page, it renders http://backend , and not the actual web address.

here is my config on the downstream

```
upstream backend {
     server unix:///var/www/my_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen         80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: That worked Thanks.